# Why does plink have an issue with brackets?

Tags: shell, ksh, plink

I'm trying to use plink to run a pl/sql package on a remote service running the ksh shell. I can connect and everything is fine but I cannot pass a ( bracket to plink without ksh throwing up an error.

When I type this from a dos command prompt:

```
plink myuser@server -pw password echo "This is a test"
```

everything works fine. But when I type

```
plink myuser@server -pw password echo "This is a test ( )"
```

I get:-

```
 ksh: 0403-057 Syntax error at line 1 : `(' is not expected.
```

I have the same problem when calling packages. If the package has a ( then it fails when called through plink but runs fine when entered directly into a putty window.

Does anyone know why plink/ksh has a problem with brackets?

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.osdevice/korn_shell_quote_chars.htm

Comment: Works fine. Thanks !

Comment: Great! Please add an answer and self-accept so others have benefit of this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to escape the brackets with an '\' ie

```
plink myuser@server -pw password echo "This is a test \( \)"
```

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.osdevice/korn_shell_quote_chars.htm